# How to create periodic matrix using single vector in matlab?

Tags: arrays, matlab, matrix

I'm trying to create circular or periodic sift matrix from a given vector of 57142x1, which is my actual vector, but for the test I tried using a simple 3x1 vector. My code, using `circshift` in Matlab, is

```
v=[1 2 3]';
A=[];
A=[v,circshift(v,1),circshift(v,2)];
```

For this code, I got as answer:

```
A =
     1     3     2
     2     1     3
     3     2     1
```

so I got correct output for 3x1 small vector,  but how should I do the same using the loop or vector-based method for 57142x1 vector?

Comment: may I ask why you actually need a matrix form?

Comment: bla I need an above matrix form to compute something which you get in the following link -https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2749845/how-to-express-the-cross-correlation-of-two-sequence-in-system-of-linear-equatio

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A simple approach:

```
v=[1 2 3]';
A = [];
for j = 1:length(v)
    A = [A,circshift(v,j-1)];
end
```

Now, you can replace 'v' with any generalised matrix.

Answer (score 2):

With the for loop:

```
 N=57142;
 v=[1:N].';
 A=zeros(size(v));

 for j=1:N
     A(:,j)=circshift(v,j);
 end
```

It is possible to code it in a more concise form using some built-in function, e.g. `arrayfun`, but this will not improve the performance.

As an alternative, the elegant solution is to use `toeplitz` function:

```
 N=57142;
 v=[1:N].';
 toeplitz(v,[v(1);flip(v(2:end))]);
```

EDIT:
Note aside, the double array of size `57142x57142` takes 24.3 GB RAM. Be careful!

Comment: while making this matrix I got the following error for 57142x1 vector :                              
Error in toeplitz (line 42)
ij = bsxfun(@plus, cidx, ridx);         % Toeplitz subscripts

Comment: @anil this might be due to different Matlab versions. In my Matlab 2017b, the above code works well

Answer (score 1):

The following works for arbitrary size:

```
v = [1 2 3].';
n = numel(v);
A = v(mod(bsxfun(@minus, (1:n).', 0:n-1) - 1, n) + 1);
```